# How to restore a database from a .bak file to an existing database via GUI?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore

How can I restore a database from a .bak file to an existing database via the GUI instead of using the commands? Will the database be inconsistent if I restore a previous backup and what will happen to the current state of the running database?

Comment: Hi James,thanks a bunch for response but isnt there any way to keep the current db data and also restore the previous backup so that both the data exists?

Comment: You could restore the data to a different database by entering a different database name in the destination section. You can't merge the two databases without scripting or a 3rd party tool like Redgate backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the databases folder in the tree on the left in SSMS and select restore database.

The restore task will remove the existing database and then create the restored database. Remember to select overwrite on tick box on the options tab.